How to attach a link to a Drupal slick slide paragraph using link from the image media?
I'm working on a Drupal 10 site where we have a entity reference paragraph used to include multiple types on paragraphs. One paragraph type is for slideshows rendered with Slick. These include images and captions, where some of the Media used for images include a link field.
I'm trying to attach these links to the slide image so the user can click the image and follow the link. I've tried preprocess_slick, preprocess_field and my image formatter. I've seen the link in the structure but it's never attached properly.
Will editing one of the theme preprocess functions work or am I going about this the wrong way?
